# unit testing -Mock JNDI lookup in WebSphere LIberty

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, jndi, websphere-liberty

I am using WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5 server and writing some batch test cases on this server. I am trying to mock jndi lookup object for testing but while setting up dataSource object in test case I am getting below error, Does anyone know how to set  INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY

> ERROR :  javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system prop
>   erty, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
>           at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the class name of your initial context factory in the environment of the InitialContext constructor.

For example:

```
Hashtable<Object, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
env.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.example.MockICF");
new InitialContext(env);
```

Where `com.example.MockICF` might be written as:

```
public class MockICF implements InitialContextFactory {

    private static Context ctx = new Mockery().mock(Context.class);

    @Override
    public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws NamingException {
        return ctx;
    }
}
```